# How to auto login the user node.js+ passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have used node.js and passport.js to create the login application. I am using express-session and connect-mongo to maintain the session. I want the user to be directly moved to the home page every time he accesses the url. He should be directed to the login page only if the user has not logged in once. How can I attain that.

Login.js

```
module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback : true
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) { 
            // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
            User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, 
                function(err, user) {
                    // In case of any error, return using the done method
                    if (err)
                        return done(err);
                    // Username does not exist, log the error and redirect back
                    if (!user){
                        console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'User Not found.'));                 
                    }
                    // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
                    if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                        console.log('Invalid Password');
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Invalid Password')); // redirect back to login page
                    }
                        // User and password both match, return user from done method
                    // which will be treated like success
                    return done(null, user);
                }
            );

        })
    );


    var isValidPassword = function(user, password){
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    }

}
```

Signup.js

```
module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {

            findOrCreateUser = function(){
                // find a user in Mongo with provided username
                User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
                    // In case of any error, return using the done method
                    if (err){
                        console.log('Error in SignUp: '+err);
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    // already exists
                    if (user) {
                        console.log('User already exists with username: '+username);
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('message','User Already Exists'));
                    } else {
                        // if there is no user with that email
                        // create the user
                        var newUser = new User();

                        // set the user's local credentials
                        newUser.username = username;
                        newUser.password = createHash(password);
                        newUser.email = req.param('email');
                        newUser.firstName = req.param('firstName');
                        newUser.lastName = req.param('lastName');

                        // save the user
                        newUser.save(function(err) {
                            if (err){
                                console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);  
                                throw err;  
                            }
                            console.log('User Registration succesful');    
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        });
                    }
                });
            };
            // Delay the execution of findOrCreateUser and execute the method
            // in the next tick of the event loop
            process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
        })
    );

    // Generates hash using bCrypt
    var createHash = function(password){
        return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
    }

}
```

index.js

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    // if user is authenticated in the session, call the next() to call the next request handler 
    // Passport adds this method to request object. A middleware is allowed to add properties to
    // request and response objects
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    // if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
    res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = function(passport){

    /* GET login page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
        res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message') });
    });

    /* Handle Login POST */
    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash : true  
    }));

    /* GET Registration Page */
    router.get('/signup', function(req, res){
        res.render('register',{message: req.flash('message')});
    });

    /* Handle Registration POST */
    router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/signup',
        failureFlash : true  
    }));

    /* GET Home Page */
    router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
        res.render('home', { user: req.user });
    });

    /* Handle Logout */
    router.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    return router;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried yourself? That also depends on client-side code, which you did not provide.

Comment: @E_net4 I haven't implemented the client side code yet.

Comment: Well, that is something you should work on before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session data is usually stored on a client side in form of a cookie, or stored in local storage. Your UI application should check if this data is present, and redirect the authenticated user to a specific URL (everything on a client side, no interaction with a server).

On a first request made by UI (with data from cookie or local storage), you can revalidate this data (on server) passed from UI, and if its not valid you can refresh session data and return it to a user or logout this user (depends on a workflow).